# Как сделать такой слайдер-переключатель?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, material-design

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При переключении он как бы переезжает с одной позиции на другую. То есть, это не просто переключатель. Хотя мне хотя бы и без анимации сделать))

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - использовать библиотеку. Вот есть [такой вариант](https://github.com/addisonElliott/SegmentedButton). Подключается все просто:

```
implementation 'com.github.addisonelliott:SegmentedButton:$LATEST_VERSION'
```

И так добавить можно в макет разметки:

```
<co.ceryle.segmentedbutton.SegmentedButtonGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:sbg_animateSelector="bounce"
        app:sbg_animateSelectorDuration="1000"
        app:sbg_backgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:sbg_dividerColor="@color/grey_500"
        app:sbg_dividerPadding="10dp"
        app:sbg_dividerRadius="10dp"
        app:sbg_dividerSize="1dp"
        app:sbg_position="1"
        app:sbg_radius="2dp"
        app:sbg_ripple="true"
        app:sbg_rippleColor="@color/grey_500"
        app:sbg_selectorColor="@color/grey_500"
        app:sbg_selectorTextColor="@color/white"
        app:sbg_shadow="true"
        app:sbg_shadowElevation="3dp"
        app:sbg_shadowMargin="4dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="10dp"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="10dp"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="10dp"
            android:text="Button 3"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

    </co.ceryle.segmentedbutton.SegmentedButtonGroup>
```

Вот есть туториал по еще [одной библиотеке](https://androidexample365.com/a-simple-android-ui-library-for-segmented-controls-with-material-ish-styling/). Еще [одна библиотека](https://github.com/creageek/segmented) и вот [тут есть сборище](https://android-arsenal.com/) всяких библиотек можете еще тут поискать. Вот [такую библиотеку](https://github.com/BelkaLab/Android-Toggle-Switch) использую я у себя, но тут судя по всему нету анимации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]